# Check all fields in a dijit form

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

Is there any way I can loop through all the dijit fields in a dijit form and print out whether they are valid. I only ask because my 'onValidStateChange' function disables my submit button and I don't know why it wont re-enable it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get use the dijit.form.Form's  `getChildren()` to get all of the child widgets in a form, and then use `isValid()` to check whether the field is valid;

```
var form, iterFunction;
form = dijit.byId('form');
iterFunction = function(widget){
    console.log(widget.isValid());
};
dojo.forEach(form.getChildren(), iterFunction);
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify what child elements can be connected ? lets say you have a wizard form with different panes and you do not want to validate the entire form however you would like to validate on certain elements. How is that achieved?

Comment: @devdar i have updated the special case in below answer and also in your original question too :) check it out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033196/dojo-displaying-multiple-tooltip-on-page/

Answer (score 3):

By default, `form.validate()` will validate all the child widgets too. If any form widgets are added/removed dynamically to/from the form respectively, then connect all the child widgets and then validate

```
form = dijit.byId('form_id');
form.connectChildren();
form.validate();
```

if the form has multiple tabs (TabContainer), the "connectChildren" function will actually attach all the fields at all descendant levels to the parent form object. We need not run a loop manually, until unless the particular fields need to be known for any more manipulations.

For special case: If form contains many tabs and need to validate per form at a time and navigate
for eg: cp1 and cp2 are the 2 tabs

```
var mytab1 = dijit.byId("cp1");
var canNavigate = true;
var highlight = function(widget){
   var v = widget.validate;
   if(!v) return true;
   widget._hasBeenBlurred = true;
   if(!widget.validate()) {
     canNavigate = false;
   }
};
dojo.forEach(mytab1.getChildren(), highlight);
if(canNavigate) {
   dijit.byId("tc").selectChild("cp2");
}
```

Complete example :- http://jsfiddle.net/ZtzTE/29/

Comment: I've decided to move from dojo to jQuery in the end. I found I had to hack to much with dojo :(

Comment: Is there a way to specify what child elements can be connected ? lets say you have a wizard form with different panes and you do not want to validate the entire form however you would like to validate on certain elements. How is that achieved?