# Dojo displaying multiple tooltip on page

Tags: javascript, tooltip, dojo, dijit.form

I have a Dojo form and i would like to return errors to the form and display them in tool tips since i do not want to add extra elements to my form layout. On researching i saw Dojo doesn't allow for such implementation out of the box since the tool tip will only be displayed in items in focus. In my case i would like tool tips to be displayed for multiple items e.g for all null fields.

I came across a blog where a guy did a [hack](http://robertbasic.com/blog/multiple-dojo-tooltips-on-page-load) however i am not sure about his implementation of such. I would like to display multiple tool tips for multiple items. Here is also a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devdarin/ZtzTE/) of what i have done thus far. The tooltip only shows for the last item.

**Dojo Form**

```
<body class="claro">
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="
            regExp: '[\\w]+',
            required: true,
            invalidMessage: 'First Name Required !'" id="fnameTextBox" title="First Name" placeholder="Your First Name" />
    <input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" data-dojo-props="
            regExp: '[\\w]+',
            required: true,
            invalidMessage: 'Last Name Required !'" id="lnameTextBox" title="Last Name" placeholder="Your Last Name" />
    <button id="validateFields" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Validate</button>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
 dojo.require("dijit/form/Button");
 dojo.require("dijit/form/ValidationTextBox");
 dojo.require("dijit/Tooltip");

 dojo.ready(function () {

     var fName = dijit.byId("fnameTextBox");
     var lName = dijit.byId("lnameTextBox");

     dojo.connect(dijit.byId("validateFields"), "onClick", function () {

         dijit.showTooltip(
         fName.get('invalidMessage'),
         fName.domNode,
         fName.get('tooltipPosition'), !fName.isLeftToRight());

         dijit.showTooltip(
         lName.get('invalidMessage'),
         lName.domNode,
         lName.get('tooltipPosition'), !lName.isLeftToRight());


     });

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing all the tool tips is not advisable though, from the perspective of user experience. Although all invalid fields can be highlighted. Tooltip are designed to display only when we focus on it.
In you case, you move the focus to the lastname field, by adding "dijit.showTooltip".
I updated your code. Please refer - http://jsfiddle.net/ZtzTE/26/

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("validateFields"), "onClick", function() {      
   var myform = dijit.byId('myform');
   myform.connectChildren();
   myform.validate();
});
```

"connectChildren" is to connect all fields to form before validating. (Note that some fields might have been added programmatically later).
(Note: I added "missingMessage" attribute to the validation text boxes, in case you have missed them. Because, "Invalid message" and "missingMessage" are different).

If no fields are filled, the by default form will have focus on first field. So, initially the message will appear for first field even if not focused. But, if first field is filled and no other field is focused, then missingMessage appears only when focus is made to the respective field. Same applies to the invalid input and message too.

Partial Validation of form:
If only few fields are to be validated in a form, then we can do it manually.
http://jsfiddle.net/ZtzTE/29/ -  Check this complete example(updated)

//cp1 and cp2 are the two content panes of tab container

```
var mytab1 = dijit.byId("cp1");
var canNavigate = true;
var highlight = function(widget){
   var v = widget.validate;
   if(!v) return true;
   widget._hasBeenBlurred = true;
   if(!widget.validate()) {
     canNavigate = false;
   }
};
dojo.forEach(mytab1.getChildren(), highlight);
if(canNavigate) {
   dijit.byId("tc").selectChild("cp2");
}
```

Comment: This is not a bad answer and i like the way it works

Comment: Can i do the same if my items are in a dojox.layout.TableContainer as you did with the form tag. The application is in a wizard form and is only contained in one form tag. using the form tag would cause validation on other pages in the wizard. So can i do the same for a TableContainer?

Comment: "validate" is a function on form, which is useful to validate all fields enclosed within with a single call. TabContainer does not have the validate function. Moreover, calling "validate" on that particular form will not validate any other forms :)

Comment: One more bonus is that, your form in turn can contain a TabContainer and too many fields in each container. We still can use the same - form.validate(); (irrespective of content panes)

Comment: That would validate all fields I am using a form wizard and doing validation in each next button so I only want to return errors for fields on te current page and not the entire wizard form. Any suggestions on that ?

Comment: I implemented your answer however the form is divided into panes using the wizard pane and the entire wizard is in one form tag. All panes have fields so the validator isn't letting me move to the next pane since the fields on the other panes are getting validated and the validate function is always returning false. How can i over come this?

Comment: either you create multiple forms for easy coding or we can do manually tab by tab. check the update answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers however I must use a wizard form so all my items are on separate panes. I cannot use tabs. Is there a way to achieve it using the wizard panes. I understand with the tabs you can have multiple forms however with a wizard you can have only one form tag.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtzTE/29/ - Follow the same approach. Get list of all the fields and validate them manually by iterating the list. "getDescendants" is a method available in many widgets, to get the entire sub-tree from a specific DOM node. Your wizard form would have a similar name. If not, write your own.

Comment: great thank alot for your time wish i could have given you more points for your answers

Comment: I wish i could learn something more new out of your doubts :)

Comment: I guess you are very good at using dojo. Thanks again for your assistance

Comment: can you assist with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23068497/dojo-dijit-setting-invalid-message-and-failing-validation

Comment: can you assist with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635574/dojo-date-constraint