# Dojo/Dijit setting invalid message and failing validation

Tags: javascript, validation, dojo, dijit.form

I have a form item with **missingMessage** and **invalidMessage** defined for the item. I call the form validation method on the item for validation. If the item is empty the **missingMessage** is called and the red exclamation mark error icon is shown.

I am trying to set the **invalidMessage** on text item when the user enters a specific value how can i get the **invalidMessage** and the red exclamation mark to show  without hard coding a constraint on the text item.

I would like to use this for custom validation on items. If the user enters a particular value i would like fail the validation and return an error. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/devdarin/ZtzTE/31/) i am trying to tell the user they cannot enter the value *'John'* in the first name field. I am getting the red exclamation mark set however the **invalidMessage** is not showing.

I would like when the user clicks on the exclamation mark they can see the error message and when they begin to type or change the contents of the field the exclamation mark nad error message is no longer shown.

**Jsp**

```
<body class="claro">
    <form id="myform" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Form">

    <input
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
        data-dojo-props="
            regExp: '[\\w]+',
            required: true,
            invalidMessage: 'Invalid First Name !',
            missingMessage: 'First Name Required !'"
        id="fnameTextBox" title="First Name"
    placeholder="Your First Name"
    />

    <input
    data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
        data-dojo-props="
            regExp: '[\\w]+',
            required: true,
            invalidMessage: 'Invalid Last Name !',
            missingMessage: 'Last Name Required !'"
        id="lnameTextBox" title="Last Name"
    placeholder="Your Last Name"
    />

     <button id="validateFields" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button">Validate</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
dojo.require("dijit/form/Form");
dojo.require("dijit/form/Button");
dojo.require("dijit/form/ValidationTextBox");
dojo.require("dijit/Tooltip");

dojo.ready(function() {
    var fName = dijit.byId("fnameTextBox");
    var lName = dijit.byId("lnameTextBox"); 

    dojo.connect(dijit.byId("validateFields"), "onClick", function() {      
        var myform = dijit.byId('myform');
        myform.connectChildren();   


        if(fName == "John"){
            dijit.byId("fnameTextBox")._set("state","Error");
            dijit.byId("fnameTextBox").attr('_ErrorMessage', 'John is not allowed');

        }else{
             myform.validate();
        }

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **best practice method** to provide separate validation rules for a particular widget is overriding the default `validator()` method of that widget.

```
var fnameTextBox = dijit.byId('fnameTextBox');
fnameTextBox.validator = function() {
   if(this.value.indexOf("John")>-1) {
     this.set("invalidMessage",this.value+" is not allowed!");
     return false;
   }
   return true;
}
//below 2 lines to programmatically validate a specific field
fnameTextBox._hasBeenBlurred = true;
fnameTextBox.validate();
//To show the message on failing the field must be focussed
fnameTextBox.focus();
```

The validator  function can have its own logic for validating and is subjective only to this field widget. If same has to be applied to more than one, define the function instead of anonymous, and use it for the respective fields.

But, if it only a value check, we can give just a regexp expression for this.

```
regExp: '^((?!John).)*$'
```

**The following is not the best practice** to do it. Because calling form.validate() will still validate this field as true, which is not correct.

```
dijit.byId("fnameTextBox")._set("state","Error");
dijit.byId("fnameTextBox").attr('_ErrorMessage', 'John is not allowed');
```

Comment: can you assist i am looking at ajax requests http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23114089/dojo-data-not-posted-as-json

Answer (score 2):

I have not enough reputation to add a comment for @Richard comment above, also I know this question is ancient. It might help someone.

For Dojo 1.10, in order to show the error message, .focus() must go first, otherwise it will not prompt the error until the second time that the validation happens. Also to show it as Error, it should also be stated in the code:

`firstName.focus();
firstName.set("message", "John is not allowed.");
firstName.set("state", "Error");`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, setting attribute, "invalidMessage", only changes the default invalid message but does not trigger it to display, as the ValidationTextBox passes the validate() method. One way to do it is to take your approach, and instead do a

```
firstName.set("message", "John is not allowed.");
```

which will cause the tooltip to show up. In order for setMessage to display though, the textbox has to be focused, so you'll need to call

```
firstName.focus();
```

on the textbox beforehand. I've modified your fiddle to get what you were trying to do to work here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZtzTE/38/

Comment: I remove the item.focus() to allow the exclamation to be presented on both items if both have errors at the same time however when i enter the item the messages do not appear or show. How can i get the messages to show when i enter the items ?

Comment: I just edited the fiddle (the new link is in the original post) to remove the if else statement. What I would do instead is that I perform the form validation first, and then do any subsequent additional validation checks that you can define afterwards.

Comment: The only issue i am facing is the message does not display when i enter the fields if both has errors i need for the user to be able to read the errors. The exclamation mark is present in both once i remove the focus however the message does not appear. Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/devdarin/ZtzTE/40/

Comment: If i enter John Doe i am getting the exclamation marks however no messages when i click on the exclamations and they disappear. I think i need them to disappear when the user begins typing in the field. The user needs to be able to see the error message once they click or hover on the exclamation mark

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking for but I did clean up your code a little so check this fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtzTE/41/

Comment: Ok you saw the message 'John is not allowed' came up i am not able to see the second message 'Doe is not allowed' when i click in the surname field the exclamation mark goes away and the user only saw the firstname error message and did not see the surname error message even if focus is set to the surname field

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying now. With the way the current Dojo ValidationTextBoxes are implemented, the approach in the answer above may not get you to the solution you want. I think what you might need to do instead is use regular expressions in the ValidationTextBox constraint attribute to do this then.