# Dojo XhrPost set name for posted json object on server

Tags: ajax, json, dojo, http-headers

I have a **Dojo ajax** request and i am posting the data as **json** however the data is not reaching the server in **json** format. I am also not able to see the **JSON** tab in the browsers **Net** option of the console. I need the data in **json** format on the server.

**Ajax Request**

```
 var someData = [{id:"1",age:"44",name:"John"},
                           { id:"2",age:"25",name:"Doe"},
                           { id:"3",age:"30",name:"Alice"}];

    function SendData() {

   var xhrArgs = {
        url:'processData',
        postData: someData,
         handleAs: "json",
         headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" },

        load:function(data){
            console.log('data was posted');
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

**Screenshot of server details**

I would like the JSON data under to appear in the following format under with the name MyData. How is this format possible on the server?

**JSON**

```
MyData              [Object{id:"1",age:"44",name:"John"},
                     Object{ id:"2",age:"25",name:"Doe"},
                     Object{ id:"3",age:"30",name:"Alice"}]
```

**SOURCE**

```
{"MyData":[{id:"1",age:"44",name:"John"},
               { id:"2",age:"25",name:"Doe"},
               { id:"3",age:"30",name:"Alice"}]}
```

[image]

Comment: why your url:'' is empty , set your action in url

Comment: url is mandatory. provide the path of your servlet/actionclass or whatsoever.

Comment: updated the code. I only left out the url when posting this question. The code still attempts the post however i am more interested in getting the json data posted as stated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the variable i saw it could be declared

```
var someData = [{id:"1",age:"44",name:"John"},
                           { id:"2",age:"25",name:"Doe"},
                           { id:"3",age:"30",name:"Alice"}];
var formData = {MyData:someData}
    function SendData() {

   var xhrArgs = {
        url:'processData',
        postData: dojo.toJson(formData),
         handleAs: "json",
         headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json" },

        load:function(data){
            console.log('data was posted');
        },
        error:function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
    dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually url:'' is empty in your Ajax call. Please provide action url,

for suppose

```
url: "AddTrackServlet"
```